Could not find a declaration file for module for a custom library
I have written a custom TS library, but when I try to import it into another project, I get the following error:
Could not find a declaration file for module '@org/navigation-cards-panther-test'. '../node_modules/@org/navigation-cards-panther-test/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/org__navigation-cards-panther-test` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@org/navigation-cards-panther-test';`

What build settings for my TS package do I need to change to fix this issue?
My tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "es2017.object",
      "es2017.string"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,                 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

My directory structure:
.
├── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── NavigationCardsPanther
│       └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json


Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].
